# check columns for specific values and only keep "True" only

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to make a simple function in python that checks a column for a specific value (using a boolean index).

I only want to keep the "True" values.

I was thinking something like the below code, but i am having a hard time with my logic, being a noob and all.

```py
def checkVal(df, col, val):

    res = df[col] == val

    if val == True:
    '''take only the true'''
    else:
         '''drop'''
```

The expected output should be a dataframe only holding the true values.

Comment: unrelated, but using docstrings instead of comments in that code is giving me a bad time: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/

Comment: Is `val` a single value, or a list of values?

Answer (score 2):

If `df[col]` contains Boolean values, you can simply do:

```
df = df[df['col']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just do the following? This is much simpler & preferred than dropping, especially if you want a new dataframe

```
df1 = df.loc[df['col'] == val]
```